# How to add legend to Kendo UI Gantt Chart?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, gantt-chart, kendo-gantt

I am not able to enable legend in Kendo UI Gantt chart. I tried adding the legend options in chart configuration but it doesn't seem to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/0xverzmx/

```
legend: {
    enabled: true,
    background: "green",
    position: "bottom",
    labels: {
        font: "20px sans-serif",
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **series** option instead of *views* to make it work as shown in the below code since the legend is based upon the `series.property.name`

```
series: [{
        type: "day",
      selected: true,
      visible:true

    }],
```

and then you can adjust the `UI` based upon your *requirements*

The *updated fiddle* is stated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0xverzmx/1/)

Comment: Okay but still I'm not able to enable the legend. Am I missing something?